# Unable to get same results than in concurrency in Go book sample code

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm reading Concurrency in Go: Tools and Techniques for Developers by Katherine Cox-Buday. Great read thus far, I stumbled into a block of code in the book that I wanted to test. When I run it in my IDE I get a different results and I don't know why.
here is the code:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"sync"
)

func main() {
var count int
var lock sync.Mutex
increment := func() {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    count++
    fmt.Printf("Incrementing: %d\n", count)
}
decrement := func() {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    count--
    fmt.Printf("Decrementing: %d\n", count)
}
// Increment
var arithmetic sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
    arithmetic.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer arithmetic.Done()
        increment()
    }()
}
// Decrement
for i := 0; i <= 5; i++ {
    arithmetic.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer arithmetic.Done()
        decrement()
    }()
}
arithmetic.Wait()
fmt.Println("Arithmetic complete.")
}
```

I'm getting this result:

```
$ go run main.go
Incrementing: 1
Incrementing: 2
Incrementing: 3
Incrementing: 4
Incrementing: 5
Incrementing: 6
Decrementing: 5
Decrementing: 4
Decrementing: 3
Decrementing: 2
Decrementing: 1
Decrementing: 0
Arithmetic complete.
```

Whereas in the book I should be having this result:

```
Decrementing: -1
Incrementing: 0
Decrementing: -1
Incrementing: 0
Decrementing: -1
Decrementing: -2
Decrementing: -3
Incrementing: -2
Decrementing: -3
Incrementing: -2
Incrementing: -1
Incrementing: 0
Arithmetic complete.
```

Can someone clarify it for me.

Comment: Concurrency is not deterministic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no guarantees on the running order of goroutines. Depending on how the runtime schedules them, goroutines can run in different orders when you run the program multiple times. The output you observed appears to be one of the valid interleavings of the goroutines whereas the book lists only one of the possible outputs.